# Why doesn't <> set $_, but while (<>) {} does?

Tags: perl

```
<>;
print $_
```

But this works:

```
while(<>){
  print $_;
}
```

Why doesn't the first version work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because `while (<>)` is shorthand for `while(defined($_ = <ARGV>))`, but `<>;` is just `<ARGV>;`.  You can see this with the [`B::Deparse`](http://perldoc.perl.org/B/Deparse.html) module.

Given the file `example.pl`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

<>;

while (<>) {
}
```

the command

```
perl -MO=Deparse example.pl
```

will print

```
use warnings;
use strict 'refs';
<ARGV>;
while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    ();
}
example.pl syntax OK
```

This is an example of Perl's famous [DWIM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWIM)ery.  I believe it was done to stop people from doing the wasteful

```
for (<>) {
}
```

There is no value to special casing `<>` in void context, and, in fact, it would probably be harmful since when you say `<>;` you are most often trying to throw away a line you don't want from the filehandle.  Having `$_` catch it would not be efficient or desirable.

Comment: `-Mmodule=arg1,arg2` is equivalent to `use module qw/arg1 arg2/;`, so `-MO=Deparse` is equivalent to `use O qw/deparse/;`.  The [`O`](http://perldoc.perl.org/O.html) module makes it easy to load multiple backend modules (i.e. the ones in the `B::` namespace).

Answer (score 3):

The Perl `while (<>)` statement has an implicit assignment to `$_`, which is missing in your first snippet.

This is described in [man perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I/O-Operators):

> If and only if the input symbol is the only thing inside the conditional of a `while` statement (even if disguised as a `for(;;)` loop), the value is automatically assigned to the global variable $_, destroying whatever was there previously.

Answer (score 1):

Because the 2nd one is a special case, as if you had written:

```
while (defined($_ = <>)) {
```

The 1st one is not a special case. Since you did not store
the input line anywhere, it did not get saved.